# FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage() returning null

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

After carefully trying other answer, nothing seems to work.

Notification are working fine, when I click on them and the app has been initialised.

When the app is closed or terminated it is impossible for me to redirect the user to a page because the value of the getInitialMessage() is null.

For example, this return null, but it is the home page of my Flutter app

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage() 
        .then((message) => print('Initial message: $message'))
```

Main.dart

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

 
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  
  runApp(const FrontDeskApp());
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem on Android, but it seems to work on iOS. Can you confirm this is an android-only issue you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

This may be the reason because you are using getInitialMessage() method in wrong way.

Modify your `main.dart` like the below way and test.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((remoteMessage) {

    // whenever you open the app from the terminate state by clicking on Notification message, 
       here you will get your remoteMessage.

    // Set you App Screen Redirection here.

    // Once consumed, the RemoteMessage will be removed.

  });
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

For more reference please refer to the official document for [Handling Interaction of Notification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#handling_interaction)

Comment: What is wrong about it ? You can call it in the page which is first call.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same issue. And it seems always null.

I believe the misconception is that getInitialMessage() is not filled if the app is *not* opened via clicking the push message, but by directly opening via AppIcon

The documentation says:

> The firebase-messaging package provides two ways to handle this
> interaction:
>
> getInitialMessage(): If the application is opened from a terminated
> state a Future containing a RemoteMessage will be returned. Once
> consumed, the RemoteMessage will be removed. onMessageOpenedApp: A
> Stream which posts a RemoteMessage when the application is opened from
> a background state.

And by interaction it probably refers to "For example, if a new chat message is sent via a notification and the user presses it,"

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#handling_interaction

So, seemingly there is no way to track if there is a lingering push notification, when opened by app icon.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: We may have the same underlying question in mind, which is How do the getInitialMessage() and onMessageOpenedApp() methods relate to the notification that was triggered and pushed onto the Flutter application?  Based on your findings, it may answer why you have found null responses.